# Can I install 2008 SQLExpress alongside 2005 SQLExpress?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Can I have an instance of 2005 SQLExpress and a 2008 SQLExpress server running on my machine?

Both to be accessed using the 2008 management console.  I currently have the express tools installed, but my office recently purchased a full 2008 license.  Does this come with an improved console?  And if so, can I just install these tools or do I have to un-install the express console first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a funny coincidence, I just did right that 30 minutes ago. So far, no errors. Also, the protocols and services coexist with one another. You have to specify an identifier for the new installation which has to differ from the old SQLExpress installation. I chose to name the new instance "SQLExpress2008", which is now listed alongside the previous instance "SQLExpress".

Everything seems fine, though I have to admit I am an amateur when it comes to Microsoft SQLExpress. Hope that answers your question, if you have any specific concerns I could have a look at them.

Answer (score 2):

You can have both instances co-exist on the same server. They would have different instances name and would use different ports (so if you have configured your firewall to allow access to port 1433 you would need to add more IPs) but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah 2005 and 2008 coexist just fine.  just remember to set the ram usage.

also note that visual studios 2005 and 2008 can be on the same machine as well.

you can also open up a 2005 db in 2008 and vice versa (there are some issues, but i don't know what they are)

Comment: One of common issues i face in using 2005 is date data type is not available in 2005, have a problem everytime when using 2005

Answer (score 0):

It ought to work, at least in theory. Although the question arises -- why install both, given that 2008 should be able to do everything that 2005 does?

Comment: I do work for more than one customer, one of which is using 2005 and has no plans to move.  I have a new customer with no SQL Server yet, and I though I might as well install the latest.